# Robot Framework - Can't upload files

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have the following keyword to upload files in my test case:

```
Upload IP
    SeleniumLibrary.Click Element    xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/app-root/div/div/app-permit-form/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/elicatmu-permit-wizard/div/a[2]
    Click Element    xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/app-root/div/div/app-permit-form/div/form/div[5]/blup-oc-documents-form/div/elicatmu-file-upload-group/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/elicatmu-file-upload/div/div[1]/div/a/i
    Choose File    xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/app-root/div/div/app-permit-form/div/form/div[5]/blup-oc-documents-form/div/elicatmu-file-upload-group/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/elicatmu-file-upload/div/div[1]/div/a/i    C:\\RobotProjects\\OccupationCertificate\\DOCs\\Application Form.pdf
```

When I run the test case I have the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>   (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.45.615291
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.16299 x86_64)

I already try without Click Element Keyword and the result is the same. I try too change the document path and it's the same.
I think the issue could be the chrome webdriver, but I really need to run this test on chrome.

The HTML code is:

```
<a _ngcontent-c21=""><span _ngcontent-c21="">browse files</span><i _ngcontent-c21="" class="fas fa-folder-open"></i></a>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the page?

Comment: @MateMrše I already update with HTML code. Thanks

Comment: why you are using absolute xpath use if relative is present..

Comment: @akshaypatil I try the relative xpath and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Choose File` from SeleniumLibrary, the locator for `Choose File` needs to point to an `<input>` element. You're pointing it to an `<i>` element. That would explain the error, since it seems reasonable that selenium wouldn't be able to give keyboard focus to an `<i>` element.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, any idea how to upload one file with this locator?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with

```
xpath=//span[contains(.,"browse files")]/i
```

as the locator for the element?

Comment: I have the error: Element with locator 'xpath=//span[contains(.,"browse files")]/i' not found.